# In VB with classic ASP will local variable hides the Global declaration if variable names are similar

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on classic ASP and I have declared a variable `abc` as Global variable and I also declare another variable within the scope of function the same variable `abc` in vb will local variable hides the Global declaration?

Following is the way i declared local variable:

```vb
Sub TestFunction()
  dim abc
  abc = GetItem()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is

```
<%
dim test
test = "hello"

sub tryme
  response.write test & " - 1<br>"
  dim test
  response.write test & " - 2<br>"
  test = "hello2"
  response.write test & " - 3<br>"
end sub


  response.write test & " - 0<br>"
call tryme
  response.write test & " - 4<br>"
%>
```

output:

```
hello - 0
- 1
- 2
hello2 - 3
hello - 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, take this example;

```vb
'Global Scope
Dim abc
abc = 1

Call Response.Write(Test1() & "<br />") 'Will output 2
Call Response.Write(Test2() & "<br />") 'Will output 1

'Change global variable value.
abc = 2

'Local variable abc will not be affected by the global variable value change.
Call Response.Write(Test1() & "<br />") 'Will output 2
Call Response.Write(Test2() & "<br />") 'Will output 3

Function Test1()
  'Local Scope
  Dim abc
  abc = 2
  Test1 = abc
End Function

Function Test2()
  Test2 = abc
End Function
```

Output will be;

```
2
1
2
3
```

Any locally declared variable that matches the name of a global variable will take precedent. They are in no way connected and changing the local variable `abc` will **never** affect the value of global variable `abc`.

---

**Useful links**

- [MSDN - Using Variables and Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524870%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)